# Selective Override Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
{% block very_outer_block %}
    {%block outer_block%}
        <p> "howdy wassup up" </p>
        <p>{% block inner_block%}  "I want to be overridden"  {%endblock%}</p>
    {%endblock%}
{%endblock%}
```

Is it possible to call `super()` on the `outer_block` but override the `inner_block`?

so that the output would be if `inner_block` was overidden to `"Im another text"` for example:

```
<p> "howdy wassup" </p>
<p> "Im another text" </p>
```

or if we'll override `inner_block` to `"Overridden yet again"`
so it'll be:

```
<p> "howdy wassup" </p>
<p> "Overridden yet again" </p>
```

my question is if we define blocks within blocks can we call `super()` on the `outer_block` yet override the `inner_block`?

Comment: If you don’t override the outer but only the inner block, this should work, no?

Comment: @poke no it won't infact only the inner block will show up. the outer block  is infact part of another yet block. let me edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just override the inner block like this; it doesn’t matter if the block is nested inside others. As long as you don’t overwrite those (which would make the inner blocks non-existent if you don’t redefine them), it will work just fine:

```
>>> base = '''
{% block very_outer_block %}
    {%block outer_block%}
        <p> "howdy wassup up" </p>
        <p>{% block inner_block%}  "I want to be overridden"  {%endblock%}</p>
    {%endblock%}
{%endblock%}
'''
>>> test = '''
{% extends 'base' %}
{% block inner_block %}Overriding inner only{% endblock %}
'''
>>> env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.DictLoader({ 'base': base, 'test': test }))
>>> print(env.get_template('test').render().strip('\n'))

        <p> "howdy wassup up" </p>
        <p>Overriding inner only</p>
```